# CodedUI: Not able to start test on existing browser

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to test single method rather than again executing all methods. Existing browser closes when i try to run a single method on opened browser

Comment: PHP? Javascript? Details please.

Answer (score 0):

It's unspecified, so I'm going to assume this is a VS2012 related question.

Have a look at this thread on the MSDN Forums - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/thread/5cb4ed2f-f38e-4c4a-a703-cb45dbf98c82

The interesting part for you is probably this sample code:

```
BrowserWindow window;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method1()
    {
        window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
        window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method2()
    {
        window = BrowserWindow.Locate("Bing");
        window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method3()
    {
        window = BrowserWindow.Locate("Bing");
    }
```

In your code, you can add a helper method so that when you execute a single test you can check if you can locate the existing browser window, and if you can't `Launch()` the URL you are after.

Comment: Hi,

I went through the solution provided here 
since I'm facing with the same issue
where just after the execution, browser (IE) get closed without letting me allow to do further testing in same browser, unless if I keep an instance of a browser open priory, manually. 
But the solution didn't work.  
  
`{`  <br/>
`BrowserWindow window; `  <br/>
`window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));`  <br/>
`window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;`  <br/>
`}`  <br/>